# viewer.impl.disableRollover(true); not working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Seems like something changed in Forge's library as suddenly `viewer.impl.disableRollover(true);` has stopped working.

Would anyone kindly confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
 viewer.disableHighlight(true)
```

Keep in mind that every method under `viewer.impl.` is NOT part of the public API and is subject to change from one version to another.

Comment: I understand that we need to keep in mind viewer.impl. is subject to change, but sometimes we implement code following on-line examples that leverage these calls.  Some form of documentation in a changelog like https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/3.2.1/ would be beneficial.

Comment: Here is an Autodesk example of what I mean: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-tip-disable-mouse-hover-highlight

Comment: This specific method disableHighlight was added recently but it seems it was not mentioned in the release notes. When our team writes code samples, we sometime use viewer.impl. methods because that's the only current way to get something done. When a later release of the API breaks some code written several months before, it's very hard for us to maintain all the snippets we posted. That's why you are welcome to posts your issues on Stackoverflow, I asked the author to fix that snippet.

Comment: Thank you.  I wanted to make you aware of an issue that costs unforeseen time during upgrades.