# Autodesk Viewer - What to expect from viewer.impl Multi Model methods in the future

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Im currently trying to get multi model to work with our applications existing functionality. Of all the methods I need to use for multi model, they all fall under viewer.impl. From a post made by Phillipe (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47062286/9327787) I understood that these are not public and are subjected to change in the future.

I was wondering if of the following methods will be added to the public api? Or what can we expect from these methods in the future.

viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels()

viewer.impl.selector.setAggregateSelection()

viewer.impl.selector.getAggregateSelection()

viewer.impl.unloadModel()

viewer.impl.findModel()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Viewer implementation object (object more commonly known as its member  `viewer.impl`) holds all the implementation methods for Viewer3D and is only meant to be used by Viewer.js itself, so to put in plainly - `viewer` does things like parameter validation and `viewer.impl` does the actual work (which means using them is not really that ‘hacky’ and safe to say the ones on your list have been used quite heavily and remained stable for the past few releases)

I’m sure our dev team have been made aware that there’s genuine demand from the community to incorporate these private methods into a more publically accessible feature set (far as I know though there’s no immediate plans to do so) so trust they would think twice before introducing breaking changes to these methods. However you can subscribe to our [Forge blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/rss/blog) and watch out for the release notes - all breaking changes, even the ones that’d affect certain ‘important’ private methods, would be highlighted there.